# Multiple inheritance design implementation

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have 3 classes, `A`, `B`, and `C` where `B` is an `A` and `C` is an `A`.

These classes are designed to retain history, so `A` provides a virtual method that derived classes can create to be notified when the history should be archived, called `void archive()`.

Now suddenly there is a need to have the information from `A`, `B`, and `C` in a single class and I am not sure the best approach.

I thought about creating a new class `D` that inherits from `B` and `C`, and changing their inheritance to `virtual public A` to avoid [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) and have `D::archive()` simply call `B::archive()` and `C::archive()`.

Is this a good approach? Or should I redesign the 4 classes such that I don't use multiple inheritance?

Comment: `Now suddenly there is a need to have the information from A, B, and C in a single class` - that's the root of the evil. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The information in `B` and `C` is very distinct and it was never thought or imagined the need for all the 3 classes of info. But, of course, a couple years later, somebody got a "cool" idea in their head and the interface doesn't work, so I am trying to find the best approach to change that.

Comment: It's hard to reason about this abstractly. In general you might consider composition as an alternative to inheritance, but it depends on the specifics. MI may be good when it's appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is the standard one.  C++ has multiple-inheritance, and you should feel free to use it.  It looks like you know how to do it correctly.

Comment: That's a relief to hear. I tend to try an avoid multiple inheritance as much as I can and it took a while to figure out that approach correctly, so I wanted to make sure there isn't something I missed before modifying all the code.

Comment: By the way, the other approaches suggested are valid too, but I am assuming that you need the hierarchy for polymorphism and don't want to have to change it all just for this.  Starting from scratch, you might consider interface mixins instead (and composition for code reuse), but what you are considering is ok too.

Answer (score 5):

How about using composition instead?
E.g. `class D` delegates to classes `B` and `C` instead of inheriting.
Composition can achieve same results and code is much simpler (IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

Beware of the call chain the eventual overriding methods may have:
if `B::method` calls `A::method` and `C::method` calls `A::method`, when you put them together in D, making A virtual, if `D::method` calls both `C::method` and `B::method`, you get `A::method` called twice.

When a base is made virtual, you have to avoid such re-entrancies.

Answer (score 0):

You could have D derived from A, containing two members B and C.
D::archive would call B::archive and C::archive